# error run angular 4 project the issue appear as following

Tags: angular, angular5

i develop angular 4 app  in visual studio into the  same  solution with  backed .... it  was run and it's OK ...  after add some service and  install moment  package  i got  that error
i tried to reinstall packages  and
NPM install  but not  worked

Failed to load resource:http://localhost:56800/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/http the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56800/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/http
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56800/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/http
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn (http://localhost:56800/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1188:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:56800/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:31)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:56800/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:47)
        at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (http://localhost:56800/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:34)
        at invokeTask (http://localhost:56800/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:14)
        at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (http://localhost:56800/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17)
    Error loading http://localhost:56800/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js/http as "@angular/common/http" from http://localhost:56800/app/app.module.js......

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says it all:

> the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found)

The resource you are trying to request was not found on the server.